# Smooth shading disappears in render view

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, geometry

I'm making this object :

[image]

And as you can see, it has smooth shading. However, when I go to render view :

[image]

The smooth shading disappears. The only modifier I'm using is a Bevel modifier and I have Auto Smooth on, but I tried disabling both and none seem to have an effect on the issue. The smooth shading is applied on all faces. When I switch to Eevee, the smooth shading is applied. This is very weird. Please tell me if you think you have an idea what could cause this. Thanks by advance !

[image]

Comment: it looks smooth to me, why do you say that it disappears?

Comment: There is something up with the central curved spar, which the reflections are amplifying... could youshare your file on https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ ?

Comment: @moonboots look closer on the middle part, it is not smooth. The picture does not show it very well, but it's like that eveywhere.

Comment: As Robin says, please share your file

Comment: File uploaded !

Answer (score 2):

Worked it out ! It had to do with the material that I had copied from elsewhere, it had a normal map and that somehow messed up the display. I still have a problem with the bevel modifier but I can live with that.